# Sometimes after clicking a Button, text disappears, sometimes I have to click twice before it works

Tags: android, button

I don't know what's the problem with this button. After clicking the button, the text will disappear and after I click twice it starts working. All buttons are the same and after clicking one time the text disappears... do I need to re-do the project?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3868O.png)

**Here is the button Onclick.**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(e_Txn.getText().toString(),
                        e_Name.getText().toString(),
                        e_Amount.getText().toString(),
                        Display_date.getText().toString().trim(),
                        e_Description.getText().toString(),
                        Description.getSelectedItem().toString());

                if (isInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });
        New.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                e_Name.getText().clear();
                e_Amount.getText().clear();
                e_Txn.getText().clear();
                e_Description.getText().clear();
            }
        });
    }
```

**I opened a method for "SetOnclick"**

```
private void setOnClick() {
        this.New.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Save.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Print.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Back.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: Show the code where you init New, Save, Print, Back button.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for you to call `Save.setOnClickListener()` and `New.setOnClickListener()` methods in `onClick()`?

Comment: It fixed. Thank guys~ <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the root cause but I think you have wrong approach with your code, please do not `setOnClickListener` in `onClick()` method.

Let's make it simple

```
private void setOnClick() {
        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(e_Txn.getText().toString(),
                        e_Name.getText().toString(),
                        e_Amount.getText().toString(),
                        Display_date.getText().toString().trim(),
                        e_Description.getText().toString(),
                        Description.getSelectedItem().toString());

                if (isInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });
        New.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                e_Name.getText().clear();
                e_Amount.getText().clear();
                e_Txn.getText().clear();
                e_Description.getText().clear();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write onclick method as follows

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.Save://relpace Save with the button id
            boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(e_Txn.getText().toString(),
                    e_Name.getText().toString(),
                    e_Amount.getText().toString(),
                    Display_date.getText().toString().trim(),
                    e_Description.getText().toString(),
                    Description.getSelectedItem().toString());

            if (isInserted == true) {
                Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.New://relpace New with the button id
            e_Name.getText().clear();
            e_Amount.getText().clear();
            e_Txn.getText().clear();
            e_Description.getText().clear();
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as per my reading, you're setting click listeners again in `onClick()` method which is called when one of 4 buttons you're setting click listeners in `setOnClick()` is clicked.
For example, you have to click twice on New button to be able to do what you want.

To fix this, I'd suggest to do like following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == Save) {
        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(e_Txn.getText().toString(),
                e_Name.getText().toString(),
                e_Amount.getText().toString(),
                Display_date.getText().toString().trim(),
                e_Description.getText().toString(),
                Description.getSelectedItem().toString());
        if (isInserted == true) {
            Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else if {v == New) {
        e_Name.getText().clear();
        e_Amount.getText().clear();
        e_Txn.getText().clear();
        e_Description.getText().clear();
     }
}
```

The other method should be the same.

The reason of text disappearing isn't related to the code you posted here I think. Maybe that's caused from the other parts like styles or layouts, etc.